# SKPaymentQueue getting SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed when OFFLINE and for products that no longer exist in the store

Tags: in-app-purchase, ios9

I'm adding In-App-Purchase (IAP) to my App. I've followed all the guidelines regarding setting up a test user for the Sandbox and logging OUT of the real App Store account. While testing I was buying and cancelling. At one point the device re-sync'd with iTunes and apparently restored and re-connected me to the production store. I didn't notice this until an attempt to buy didn't produce the normal login dialog, which I cancelled. Since that point I've been getting `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` in:

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions

And the error SKError in the Error object indicates: **SKErrorPaymentCancelled** which was true but also happened days ago.

I get this regardless of if the device is connected to the internet or not (even if wifi is off). It appears to have cached the fact that the transaction was cancelled someplace and is stuck. Nothing clears it that I have tried including:

- Creating a new test user and deleting the old one.
- Deleting the App and re-installing.
- Deleting the test products that generate this.
- Clean and re-build the project including build folder.
- Resetting the device and all the other voodoo.

Any ideas what is going on here? How does one clear what is cached? It doesn't appear that I am required to acknowledge that fact to the store in anyway. Furthermore, what I find ***really odd*** is that I get these  `SKPaymentTransaction` notifications at launch, EVEN if the device is offline?!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**: Well the App Store was caching something on the device and the only solution was to re-install iOS 9 and to NOT restore from a previous backup. Cleaning the project and the build folder did not help, neither did deleting the App from the device or any of the places that iTunes stores it and then re-installing the production App.